# Android Navigation Safe Args Pass LiveData and Lambda Variable

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph, android-safe-args

I have two questions for a simple `Fragment A -> Fragment B` graph:

1. Can I pass `LiveData` using **safe args**? If not, how can I listen the value changes in `Fragment B` from `Fragment A`?
2. Can I pass lambda varible (function) using **safe args** (to act like a callback listener)?

Comment: For first, You can share your ViewModel between fragments. Init this ViewModel in Activity and share between fragments. Now using the same ViewModel instance, we can observe live-data from both fragments.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the [APIs specifically built for returning a result](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result)?

Answer (score 1):

you cant pass a LiveData using safe args but you can use the [Fragment Result API](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result) to listen value changes in other fragments

```
// in fragment A
setFragmentResultListener("requestKey") { requestKey, bundle ->
    // read bundle here
}
// in fragment B
setFragmentResult("requestKey", bundle)
```

it can be combined with your SafeArgs classes:

```
setFragmentResultListener("requestKey") { requestKey, bundle ->
    val args = MyFragmentArgs.fromBundle(bundle)
}
// Fragment B
setFragmentResult("requestKey", MyFragmentArgs(...).toBundle())
```